# How do I start using CQRS with Axon framework on an existing database

Tags: cqrs, axon

We have an existing webapplication using a graph database which we want to switch to an architecture using cqrs with the Axon framework.

I am wondering if there are any best practices what to do with the data that is already in our production database. We need to fill an index database (elasticsearch) which I would like to keep updated using event listeners. This index needs to be initialized with the data already in production, but have no associated events with them.

My first thought is just to generate a bunch of create commands from the existing database, so the filling of the index is done only with events. This probably takes a while on first run, but we're probably ok with that.

Does this sound like a good idea? Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: try to ask in axon community https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/axonframework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating an application to CQRS is not an easy task, and definitely not something to be done in a single step. However, if the application is set up properly, it's definitely possible to slowly move towards (more) CQRS.

As your challenge seems to be to add an extra view model (the ElasticSearch one), my advice would be to start by publishing Events. In Axon Framework, this would mean defining an Event Bus and publishing messages to it.

On the "Elastic-side", define a number of Event Handlers that listen to those events and make the necessary updates to your model there. You can choose to put the necessary data inside the events, or simply use the Events as a "trigger" to query the current state from your application.

A next step could be to use Command Handlers, a Command Bus and Command Messages for changes requested by your front-end (or integration) components. 
Once you have those, you can start thinking of taking out these Command Handler components into a separate component (using events to update the query components that are left after the separation).

Before doing each step, consider the amount of work and the actual advantages they give you. It might, for example, not be worth taking out the Command Handling components. Sending out Events from a "monolith" might already give you enough flexibility to build separate components around it.

Comment: I actually gave a webinar about this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YZZo19xStw. Maybe that helps give some more context.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share some experience:

- I started with the Command Gateway and Command Handlers to dispatch and manage commands in my Spring MVC Controllers and Task Schedulers.
- The Events also look interesting, however, I have yet to find a way to integrate Events (without Event Sourcing) to the existing spring-data or mybatis persistence layer.

Will appreciate if there is any example on this aspect :-)